# How to give test report using selenium Rc?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

On exporting the test cases (that have been prepared using Selenium IDE) by a JUnit formatter and using Java platform, browser and Selenium window closes on running the test case.

How can I track the test case result?

Comment: Do you mean you want a report that looks like the IDE (visual) showing which have passed or failed or do you just want a passed/failed report in XML that has the info but isnt very visual?

Comment: Yes, i need to show the test report that includes the test activites

Comment: but, i dont know how to show in Rc?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate HTML reports via Junit assert checks or write the results in a csv/html using java code. Methods such as isElementPresent will return boolean. You can write the results in a file and generate report.

Comment: Can u please explain me in detail

Comment: i need a file that would produce the report auotmatically. Please include step by step process

Answer (score 0):

If you use a TestSuite generated with Selenium IDE you can launch Selenium RC with a similar command :

```
java -jar C:\SeleniumServer\selenium-server.jar "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -htmlSuite "*chrome" "http://127.0.0.1" "C:\Path\To\TestSuite.html" "C:\Path\To\Results.html"
```

It'll produce the HTML report you're looking for.